# Unsupported Media Type with Apache HttpClient 4.x

Tags: java, cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have been trying to obtain a cookie from HTTP POST request, which is used to authenticate on a specific REST API with username and password. The problem lies in the fact that there are no cookies inside cookie store (all relevant hidden parameters are correct). The body of the POST method that is used to authenticate the user (JSON) is :

```
{
  "username": <username>,
  "password": <password>
}
```

I am using the following code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String USER_AUTHENTICATION = "/user/authentication";
    String baseUrl = "http://<someIP>/<someProjectName>/rest";

    HttpClient http = null;
    CookieStore httpCookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    RequestConfig globalConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build();
    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("<someUsername>", "<somePassword>"));

    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCookieStore(httpCookieStore)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(globalConfig).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
    http = builder.build();

    HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(baseUrl + USER_AUTHENTICATION);
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    try {
        httpResponse = http.execute(httpRequest);
    } catch (Throwable error) {
        throw new RuntimeException(error);
    }

    List<Cookie> cookies = httpCookieStore.getCookies();
    System.out.println("Cookies! " + cookies);
}
```

The console output is:

```
12:09:34.267 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: standard
12:09:34.295 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
12:09:34.298 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {}->http://<someIP>][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
12:09:34.343 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://<someIP>][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
12:09:34.346 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {}->http://<someIP>
12:09:34.355 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to /<someIP>
12:09:34.363 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established <someOtherIP>:<somePort><-><someIP>
12:09:34.363 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Executing request POST /<someProjectName>/rest/user/authentication HTTP/1.1
12:09:34.363 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
12:09:34.365 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
12:09:34.368 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> POST /<someProjectName>/rest/user/authentication HTTP/1.1
12:09:34.369 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 0
12:09:34.369 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: <someIP>
12:09:34.369 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
12:09:34.369 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_91)
12:09:34.369 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
12:09:34.369 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /<someProjectName>/rest/user/authentication HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.369 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.369 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: <someIP>[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.369 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.369 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_91)[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.370 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.370 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.406 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.406 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 11:09:39 GMT[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.406 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.406 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.406 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.406 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.406 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.406 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
12:09:34.413 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
12:09:34.413 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 11:09:39 GMT
12:09:34.413 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
12:09:34.413 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 0
12:09:34.413 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
12:09:34.413 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Connection: close
12:09:34.413 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
12:09:34.419 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
12:09:34.420 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
12:09:34.420 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://<someIP>][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
Cookies! []
```

My thoughts: there might be a problem with unsupported media type, which can be seen in the console output, but I do not know how to solve it :(

EDIT: I have received advice to add additional info about the app, so here it goes: the task is to obtain a cookie which will be passed around in various requests to the REST API. To do so, i first have to authenticate (POST) with a username and password which will provide the cookie itself, and then i should check if the cookie is the same in all other REST requests (I have tested the POST method with Postman and it works). To admit, this is my first time coding in Java, which includes REST architecture, even though i understand the basics of basics, I chose google and SO which lead me here. So .. is code from my example necessary or it can be simplified ? Ty for the answers, I am very grateful :)

Comment: You should change the title to the question, it has nothing to do with cookies.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that stands out is that `POST /<someProjectName>/rest/user/authentication HTTP/1.1` has `Content-Length: 0` are you sure you are sending the data ?

Also the server responds with 415, which is probably because you are sending `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8` and you should probably send `application/json; charset=UTF-8`. You may also want to set the Accept header to `application/json`, to tell the server you expect the response to be JSON.

If you are only calling JSON based REST API it seem very low level to use HTTP Client directly. Personally I would use Springs RestTemplate (which can also be configured to use HttpClient and connection pooling), the code will be 5 times shorter, and easier to read.

Comment: I have set the`httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");` and `httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");`, but then i get `org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8` and 500 internal server error. Should there be any JSON objects processed ?

Comment: When I look at your example it looks like you copied it from somewhere else. You have CredentialsProvider, this is typically used for Basic Authentication, and should probably not be used if you need to post user/pass to the service. Also you almost never use Cookies with REST services, typically the call to authenticate returns a token that you must add to future requests. To me it sounds like you are in over you head. Unless you can provide a version of the REST service that can be accessed from the internet I don't think I can help.

Comment: Do you have documentation on the endpoints, then perhaps I can build a dummy application that behaves the same way.

Comment: I have added additional info in my OP, thank you for helping out :)